# How can I use choice.showOpenDialog(parent) in netbeans?

Tags: java, jframe, parent-child, parent, jfilechooser

Sorry about my poor knowledge in java, but the thing is -

I have a `jFrame` Form in netbeans called BackUp -

```
public class BackUp extends javax.swing.JFrame
```

This has an icon I set up and I want to pass it into a `jFileChooser` using:

```
JFileChooser choice = new JFileChooser()
choice.showOpenDialog(parent);
```

but I do not know what to write to replace "parent". I tried with -

```
JFileChooser choice = new JFileChooser()
choice.showOpenDialog(BackUp);
```

but it appears the red bulb next.

Thanks in advance and I'll really appreciate your answers.

Comment: Since you extend JFrame just use chooser.showOpenDialog(this)

Comment: Thank you very much, Vikas Sachdeva. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you `BackUp` class `extends JFrame` simply just do: `choice.showOpenDialog(this);`

`this` is referring back to the current object which is you `BackUp` class which is extending `JFrame`

Comment: Thank you, HuffelPuff. Your comment was helpful.